# Exponentiating limit ordinals

Tags: ordinals

I have been reading about ordinal arithmetic and I came across this definition for ordinal exponentiation, when the exponent is a limit ordinal and the base isn't. Here is the definition: $$\begin{array}{lcl} \alpha^0 &= & 0' \\ \alpha^{\beta'} &= &(\alpha^\beta) \times \alpha \\ \alpha^{\lambda} &= & {\bigcup \{\alpha^\beta : \beta < \lambda\} \text{ ($\lambda$ a limit ordinal)}} \end{array}$$
The definition I am talking about is the last one.
I was wondering if there is a similar definition for when the base is also a limit ordinal. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The definition you've given is valid for any ordinal $\alpha$, not just the successors.

Comment: @PatrickStevens I see. So if I wanted to compute $\omega_1\^\omega_1\$, would I be able to do so with the current definition?

Comment: @MathGeek The ability to compute $\omega_1^{\omega_1}$ is more a matter of deciding what "computing" means. If, for instance, we decide that the goal of a computation is to express an ordinal in its Cantor normal form, then you can certainly use the definition of exponentiation to prove that $\omega_1=\omega^{\omega_1}$, hence $\omega_1^{\omega_1}=\omega^{\omega^2_1}$.

Comment: @Lahoc And we cannot simplify that further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you've written is usually given in that exact form for all ordinals $\alpha$, nor there seems to be any material reason to make a special case for $\alpha=\gamma'$. For instance, that's the definition in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) and in *Set theory* by Thomas Jech. But it should be the same in every book ever written.